# How to find all .csv files in a directory using Pharo?

Tags: csv, pharo

How can I find all files ending in `.csv` in a given directory using Pharo?

Comment: Popular in Python, so maybe here, too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work too:

```
'G:\My Drive\Data Mining' asFileReference allChildrenMatching: '*.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `basename` and `endsWith:` for the children of the directory (`FileReference`). From http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/FileSystem.pdf:

```
    working := 'G:\My Drive\Data Mining' asFileReference.
    working allChildren select: [ :each | each basename endsWith: '.csv' ]
```